# kubectl: get all images from specific deployments

Tags: kubectl

Is there any way to get images or image hashes using one kubectl command?
I'm using this

```
kubectl get deployment -A -o wide --selector=app.kubernetes.io/name=deployment_name
```

But I need only images as an output from my command.

Answer (score 1):

- we jsonpath to get that info

```
kubectl get deployment -A -o jsonpath='{range .items[*]}{.spec.template.spec.containers[*].image}{"\n"}{end}'
```

for more examples of [jsonpath](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/kubectl/cheatsheet/)

Answer (score 0):

Here is another approch using `custom-columns`:

```
kubectl get deployments.apps  -o custom-columns=image:.spec.template.spec.containers[*].image --no-headers -l app.kubernetes.io/name=deployment_name
```

Here `custom-columns` format is `<header>:<json-path-expr>,<header-1>:<json-path-expr-2>`. This is particularly helpful in making custom tablular data as follow:

```
k get deployments.apps  -o custom-columns=deployment:.metadata.name,image:.spec.template.spec.containers[*].image    -A
deployment               image
coredns                  rancher/coredns-coredns:1.8.3
traefik                  rancher/library-traefik:2.4.8
metrics-server           rancher/metrics-server:v0.3.6
local-path-provisioner   rancher/local-path-provisioner:v0.0.19
tcc-nginx-deployment     nginx
foobar                   nginx,bash
```